# PYTHON/PyTelegramBotAPI/Баны-кики участников из группы

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Сделал простенького бота, написал небольшой код для отсылки правил группы, и хочу сделать
гуард бота который может банить по команде/Ответе на сообщение, пример: бан @vasyapupkin
ну или же так с киком, принцип понят, пытался искать инфу на форумах но ничего не получилось
бот выдает ошибку, если кто то знает то помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

`bot.ban_chat_member(айди_чата, айди_участника)` — забанить участника в чате

если после этого использовать `bot.unban_chat_member(айди_чата, айди_участника)`, то его заблокирует, а потом разблокирует. то есть фактически кик.

Я использую это в ответе на сообщение пользователя, к которому нужно применить бан, таким образом `message.chat.id` — айди_чата, а `message.reply_to_message.from_user.id` — айди_участника

не забудьте сделать проверку, на то, что есть ответ на сообщение пользователя и дать боту права администратора!

Comment: Поробовал как вы сказали, но ошибка остается

Comment: покажите пожалуйста ошибку, о которой идет речь

Comment: у вас есть дискорд, или может вк или другой любой мессенджер куда мы с вами можем перейти, просто здесь обсуждать тему не очень удобно